# CSS: achieving TWO-WAY infinite scroll with mouse drag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I'm trying to create an infinite scroll component.

I'm using [this](http://ajaxdump.com/2009/09/02/horizontal-scroll-effect-using-jquery/) site as a tutorial, but it seems that I can only get the infinite scroll on one way, because when I add elements to the leftmost side, the *scrollLeft* property auto-adjusts thus the page gets a quirky scroll, jumping instead of making a smooth movement.

Is there any way of achieving infinite scroll both-ways? I don't plan to use scrolling buttons, just mouse drag for moving the scroll view.

Comment: Are you trying to do both down and right scroll, or left and right scroll?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I posted a [demo for you here](http://jsfiddle.net/5VYMD/)... basically, you just need to know the width of the content you are adding, which in this case is 310 pixels.

The script then adds the content, adjusts the scrollLeft and the width of the event panel.

```
 $('button').click(function(){
  $('li.welcome').after( $('#temp').html() );
  $('#timeline')[0].scrollLeft += 310;
  $('.tl-events').css('width', $('.tl-events').width() + 310 );
 })
```

This button click function adds the content from inside the #temp div just for this example.

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick. Although I'm using gwt to implement this and in hosted mode it's a little quirky (the scroll moves back an d forth), its working properly.

Comment: This is awesome. It's too bad this isn't easier to do with pure CSS, but this is a really great approach that is also easy to customize. Thank you!