# How to scroll page left - right where left div is out of screen

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have three divs in a page which Home, template and 3d. template and 3d div will reside out of screen.

When I click on navigation anchor, then the page scroll to the target div.

I need to use scroll function of jQuery because in future I will use this scroll function in parallex.

Below is the code which is used to scroll but getting fail to show left div which is out of screen.

and js fiddle link  http://jsfiddle.net/naresh_kumar/CEC3L/4/

```
<div id="page" class="clearfix" style="width: 1800px; left: -500px;">
    <div id="header">  
        <div class="nav-enabled">
            <ul id='navigation'>
                <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#templates">Templates</a></li>
                <li><a href="#3d">3D</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="templates" class="content" style="height: 378px; width: 516px;">
        Template
    </div>

    <div id="home" class="content" style="height: 378px;  width: 516px;">
        Home
    </div>

    <div id="3d" class="content" style="height: 378px; width: 516px;">
        3D
    </div>
</div>   

<script>
   $(function() {
       $('ul#navigation a').bind('click',function(event){
           var $anchor = $(this);
           $('html, body').stop().animate({
               scrollLeft: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().left
                   }, 1000);
               event.preventDefault();
           });
       });
</script>

<style>
    #page
    {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E6E6E8;
        height: auto;
        min-height: 100%;
        position: relative;
        top: 0;
    }
    .content
    {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E6E6E8;
        color: #000000;
        float: left;
    }
    #header
    {
        clear: both;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        display: block;
    }
    #header .nav-enabled
    {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        height: auto;
        left: 0;
        opacity: 0.72;
        padding: 20px;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        width: auto;
        z-index: 5;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13492656/infinite-scrolling-for-elements-which-are-positioned-absolute/13492819#13492819

Comment: its not working fine.. when you clicked on template then template div is not showing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `#page` div has `left: -500px`.

```
<div id="page" class="clearfix" style="width: 1800px; left: -500px;">
```

Remove that

```
<div id="page" class="clearfix" style="width: 1800px;">
```

and it works fine.

---

If you want the "home" panel to be visible on page load, then you'll need to keep the offset, and then use a little javascript, on page load, to "un-do" the offset, and adjust the scrollLeft at the same time.

http://jsfiddle.net/CEC3L/20/

Comment: your ans is right sir but "Home" div should be home screen instead of template and "Template" should come in from left.

Comment: a little bit of extra javascript will get you there: http://jsfiddle.net/CEC3L/20/

Answer (score 5):

Solved it. You can check the link

See sample below..
Just rearrange the div position.

```
<div id="home" class="content" style="height: 378px;  width: 516px;">
    Home
</div>
     <div id="templates" class="content" style="height: 378px; width: 516px;">
   Template
</div>
<div id="3d" class="content" style="height: 378px; width: 516px;">
    3D
    </div>
</div>   ​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CEC3L/8/

http://jsfiddle.net/CEC3L/26/