# Detect scroll into dom element

Tags: javascript

I want to detect scroll change into dom element, for example:

```
    <div id="box">
      ...
    </div>
```

Imagine a box `300x200`, and I want to know if someone do a scroll inside it, and how much it is. How can I know?

I prefer only use Javascript and not JQuery, because I'm not loading it and I think it's a lot for too little, but I'm open to other opinions

Comment: Have you tried something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working snippet with the current scrolled value:

```js
document.getElementById('scroll-box').onscroll = function() {
  console.log(this.scrollTop);
};
```

```css
#scroll-box {
  background-image: url(http://placekitten.com/g/300/200);
  overflow: scroll;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#elements {
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="scroll-box">
  <div id="elements"></div>
</div>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: But my element don't have scroll... I need to have the scroll variations when you are hover a image, like http://www.s--h.dk/

Comment: @ooootramas That's not images. That's span, divs, and all… with images inside. Anyway, I've added an image. (So cuuuute.)

Comment: I know, that's the reason I don't put it in the question, it's an example, I want to know if I can do the same... but only with the images

Answer (score 0):

Copied from below post, and edited for your id:
[How to capture scroll event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13492656/how-to-capture-scroll-event)

```
<div id="box" onscroll="Onscrollfnction();">

<script>
function Onscrollfnction() {
        alert("scroll");
    };
</script>
```

Comment: He also asked for the amount of the scroll. You may want to have your function pass in the `event` to help determine scroll distance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use target.addEventListener("scroll", functionName);